# Rails gem cancancan different can? and authorize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I use cancancan to authorization in my App.
In my console, i code:

```
user = User.find(1)
current_ability = Ability.new(user)
# i check can? with model Post
current_ability.can?(:manage, Post)
# => true
#but when authorize with rescue error
current_ability.authorize(:manage, Post.where(1) )
```

I don't understand, why i `can` but i don't `authorize` .
Please guide me.

Comment: If it is possible I would suggest to switch to https://github.com/varvet/pundit. I have found it to be simple and more flexible compared to other authorization gems in Rails app I have worked on. Thanks.

Comment: Please post relevant parts of your `ability.rb` and exact error that you're getting. Also fix typos, because it's most likely `authorize!` and `Post.find(1)`

Answer (score 0):

According the docs of this gem [enter link description here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), `can` to express the ability of `current_user`. This means `current_user` `can` do action, but when perform the action, if `current_user` can't perform the action then authorize will raise an exception.